# Global variable vs. constant vs. class instance variable for global cache

Tags: ruby

In general which is better for a global cache: global variable, constant, or class instance variable?

Here is an example of each:

```
module Foo
  $FOO_CACHE = {}
  def self.access_to_cache
    $FOO_CACHE
  end
end

module Foo
  CACHE = {}
  def self.access_to_cache
    CACHE
  end
end

module Foo
  @cache = {}
  def self.access_to_cache
    @cache
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

This is ultimately pretty subjective, but I’ll address each option one-by-one:

- **Global variable**: *no* …because putting a global variable inside a module (or a class, or anything for that matter) doesn’t make much sense, it’s going to be in scope everywhere anyway. Besides the fact that if you can use something other than a global variable, you should always do so.
- **Constant**: *no* …because the cache is not constant! While Ruby doesn't enforce that constants can’t change, that doesn’t mean you should do it. There’s a reason they’re called constants.
- **Class instance variable**: *yes* …because it’s the only one here that makes any sense (though the name might not, technically here it’s a module instance variable, but that’s being rather pedantic). This is the only one of the three that both makes semantic sense to modify and is encapsulated by some scope.

Comment: Good explanation! But what if I want to use/init a variable across several modules/classes/files?
I would not want to use class/module instance vars as I don't want to init class just for a sake to use its variable.
So I am left with 2 choices, class variable/constant or a global variable.
Which is better to use in such case?

Comment: @Swaps As I say in my answer: if you can use something other than a global variable, that’s the better option (and you almost always can).