# What is the difference in scoping between a global variable and a constant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, scope, global-variables, constants

In the Ruby programming language there is both the notion of a global variable, which start with a dollar sign, for example `$foo` and a constant which starts with a capital, for example `Foo`. What is the exact difference in scope of each of these two kinds of names in Ruby, and in what particular case should a global variable be preferred over a constant, or vice versa?

Comment: You can try to look at this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149158/difference-between-constant-variables-and-global-variables)

Comment: I don't think _scope_ is really the main distinguishing factor, but rather that globals can be _redefined_ while constants will raise an error (unless you use const_set). Also, if you attempt to read a global that hasn't been defined, you will just get `nil`. So in general, for static data it's better to use constants, because you get these extra checks

Comment: @maxpleaner It seems you _can_ redefined constants, even though you would get a _warning_, but not an error. For example,
```
> Foo = 10
 => 10 
> Foo
 => 10 
> Foo =9
(irb): warning: already initialized constant Foo
 => 9 
> Foo
 => 9
```
But the question indicated by @ruby_dev seems to indicate that there is some _scoping_ involved and that global variables are visible globally, whereas constants are only accessible where they are defined. I'm going to try to figure out more precisely what that means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between constant variables and global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149158/difference-between-constant-variables-and-global-variables)

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez I do think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149158/difference-between-constant-variables-and-global-variables combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687276/scope-of-constants-in-ruby-modules answers my question. Thanks for the links.

Comment: You can understand the scope of a constant by reverse-engineering the steps involved in [constant lookup](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch07s09.html), which is equally important to understand. I don't think global variables vs. constants is the right question. You obviously need constants, if for no other reason to define classes...

Comment: ...The more useful question is when should global variables be used. Though they may be useful in debugging (see, for example, the doc for [Module::nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting)), I think most coders tend to avoid using them altogether (and not just in Ruby), because of the complete lack of encapsulation. Readers who dispute this last assertion are encouraged to reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are the ones that can be accessed from anywhere. Their scope turns to be the whole of the `main` object. This means they can be used anywhere in this scope i.e anywhere in the code itself. For instance

```
module A
  module B
    class C
      $glo = 'this is glo-bal variable'
    end
  end
end

module D
  class E
    CON = 'this is con-stant'
    def call_glo
      puts $glo
    end

    def call_con
      puts CON
    end
  end

  def self.call_con
    puts CON
  end

  E.new.call_glo                 #=> "this is glo-bal variable"
end

D::E.new.call_glo                #=> "this is glo-bal variable"
D::E.new.call_con                #=> "this is con-stant"
D.call_con                       #=> Throws Error Unitialized Constant
```

While the constants are restricted to the scope they are defined in. They can only be used in the scope they are defined.

Now, as you said Constants starts with capitals, hence all the class names and module names are themselves nothing but Constants.

Now in the above example, you see the `call_glo` method is called twice. Once from the scope of `module D` while one from the `main` object scope, do you see the difference between the instantiation of `class E`?

In `module D` it is called without any scope operator `::` while outside of module we had to use the scope operator, that is the restriction of scope. Constants are bound to.